# error <identifier> expected in java

Tags: java

I am getting this error:

```
MultilevelDemo.java:63: error: <identifier> expected
    total=mark1 + mark2 + mark3;
```

This is an excerpt from the code where it is showing error:

```
class Result extends Marks
{
    private int total;

    total = mark1 + mark2 + mark3;

    void putResult()
    {
        System.out.println("Total: "+total);
    }
}
```

What may be going wrong here? Please help me find it. I can't figure it out. Please ask me to give the full code if you so required. Thank you.

Comment: You've got a statement (`total = mark1 + mark2 + mark3;`) that isn't in a method or a constructor.

Comment: Ok.. I didn't show it earlier. Thank you so much!